# What is more efficient, saving to text file or database table?

Tags: php

I'm building a blog, I have done to build the replies system and now I'm working on the "posts" system. the replies was built to be saved in a database table.
So I wonder if the posts should be saved in a table too or in text files.
And generally, what do you prefer and do more in you'r projects?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: What you're basically asking is if it's more efficient to use an existing database or to build your own.

Comment: A database. They were invented so we wouldn't have to use text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save them in your database.

By doing this you will obtain consistency (all blog-related data is in a database you can easily backup/restore) and functionality (easier to search, retrieve, process, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle the file saving, traversing and retrieve the data, then use file; otherwise, use a database.